# How to fix config.headers.Authorization "Object is possibly undefined" when using axios interceptors

Tags: typescript, axios

I got the following code :

```
loggedInAxios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (isTokenExpired('access_token')) {
      const response = await getRefreshToken();
      await refreshAccessToken(response);
    }
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => error
);
```

But typescript is complaining that config.headers.Authorization object is possibly undefined.

I found a way by adding the following:

```
if (!config) {
 config = {};
}
if (!config.headers) {
  config.headers = {};
}
```

But I do not think that this is the best way to do it...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`config` is of type `AxiosRequestConfig`, thus cannot be undefined.

On the other hand, `config.header` can indeed be.
As it's a `Record` (`export type AxiosRequestHeaders = Record<string, string>;`), you can indeed default it with an empty object:

```
loggedInAxios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    config.headers = config.headers ?? {};

    // Now config.headers can be safely used
    config.headers.Authorization = `...`

    return config;
  },
  (error) => error
);
```

Answer (score 28):

You can either use `!` (non-nullable assertion operator) to tell TypeScript that a property is not undefined or null (assuming you are 100% SURE), or check it and assign it if it's undefined.

Example 1:

```
config.headers!.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
```

Example 2:

```
config.headers = config.headers ?? {};
```

Example 3:

```
if(!config.headers) config.headers =  {};
```

I don't think there are any another ways.